# JBPM 6.1 Final with Jboss Wildfly - failed to start .WeldStartService

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jbpm

I tried running the JBoss server(Wildfly 8.1.0 Final) rolled out with jbpm 6.1 and could not get it running the `jbpm-console.war`, it has been very annoying, as the installation goes smoothly without any issues and no changes were made to any configurations, so I guess it should deploy normally.

This is the issue I am running into

```
2015-01-21 11:33:45,252 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
    Exception 0 :
    org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground() on org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup@35604eeb
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:91)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:72)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:95)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BeanInjectionTarget.java:63)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:162)
        at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78)
        at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
        at org.uberfire.commons.services.cdi.StartupBeanExtension.runPostConstruct(StartupBeanExtension.java:83)
        at org.uberfire.commons.services.cdi.StartupBeanExtension.afterDeploymentValidation(StartupBeanExtension.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:125)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:128)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:102)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:63)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:396)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:85)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:93)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:89)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.addRepository(OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.java:153)
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.addRepository(Unknown Source)
        at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl.bootstrapRepository(AdministrationServiceImpl.java:157)
        at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.bootstrapRepository(Unknown Source)
        at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground(AppSetup.java:104)
        ... 38 more

        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:37)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:396)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:85)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:93)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        ... 3 more
```

finally at the very end

```
JBAS014777: Services which failed to start:service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService
```

The server won't start no matter what.

There have been many instances of this issue reported [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/249481) and [here](https://gist.github.com/mbiarnes/bb070ca69f362f49d400)
but non of these issues have proper solutions. Any ideas on how to fix this issue ?

My environment is :

- Windows 8
- Java 1.8
- Eclipse Luna
- Jboss Wildfly 8.1 Final
- Using the default H2 database

Comment: I get the same error message with Wildfly 8.2...

Comment: @Gatschet - I know it is very annoying and the jbpm community is not very helpful. Their API is very complex, that coupled with poor documentation is just a mess. Could you up vote the question so that some one tries to answer it ?

Comment: Yes, I have been trying for days to migrate to wildfly. So far without success. The documentation is a joke! The error messages randomly... It is to despair!

Comment: You can get the latest snapshots for wildly, there is already a distribution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you are experiencing is because you are trying to start wildfly without being connected to the internet or with an intermittent connection. Remember that jBPM is a community project so you guys can help with the documentation to make it better.
Try by removing the .niogit (hidden) directory that is created inside your wildfly/bin/ directory and try to start it again.
If you want to start without the demo repository, because you are offline or you cannot get online, you can do that by setting a flag that is well described in the documentation. Section: 3.6.1. Playgrounds

```
-Dorg.kie.demo=false
```

Comment: -Thanks for the reply, but the problem is that I AM connected to the internet, but it is through a proxy, I have set the '-Dorg.kie.demo=false' in the build.xml and I ran the ant target jboss.start but still the jbpm console fails to start up.

Comment: I am going to try and do the delete the hidden folder and see if that works.

Comment: I meant `start.jboss`

Comment: I cannot find a the `.nogit` folder inside `wildfly/bin`

Comment: It is called .niogit/ and if it is not there it should be in the same directory where you start the server/demo.

Comment: The folder was inside the jbpm-installer root folder. Thanks after I deleted it it worked. Curios why this worked ? I installed jbpm-installer on a mac environment and it worked perfectly, but on the windows platform it caused issues, I know it has to do with the proxy, so is there way in the installer/server to configure proxy ?

Comment: Also strangely it crashed did not work for me when I was using JDK 7 64 bit

Comment: I am getting the same problem, but adding the above flag like above didnt work. Can anyone help?

Comment: I've spend hours trying to find solution, this one is the only one that worked for me, thanks